# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, nltk, tweepy

```
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
(sense, def_word)
for sense in senses
for def_word in sense.definition.split()
if def_word in tweet)
```

Dont know what does that error mean. Please help.

Comment: Your indentation is wayyy off.

Comment: It looks like you may have missed the parenthesis for `definition`. Should it be `for def_word in sense.definition().split()`?

Answer (score 1):

What is a `sense`?  What is its `.definition`/  Looks like it is a function.  `split` only applies to a string.  You might need to do `sense.definition().split()`.

Answer (score 1):

So your answer isn't very clear, try to be more specific in future.

- But, you are using nltk.probability module for finding probability phenomena in your experiment.
- In your example you are using ConditionalFreqDist for sense and definition_word.
  So i can suggest, that you have some sense with one or more definitions in it, and you are trying to find out is the definition_word is in tweet (maybe list of words, or something).
- Error is saying that you are trying to call method from function-object ('definition') and this method isn't there. So you need to use parentheses in your code line:

  `sense.definition().split()`
- Be sure that your definition function return string because split() is used only for string.
- Also i am not sure of how you are using ConditionalFreqDist, look at this:
  [NLTK-Tutorial](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/icl/nltk/probability.pdf) for revealing some aspects of using nltk module.

Good luck with solving the problem!